# Clickable div if nested div contains an anchor

Tags: jquery

In working with an existing example:

```
$(".card").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});
```

This applies to all instances of "card" however I have several cards with no anchors which obviously is an issue.

I'd like the navigation only to occur if there is an anchor in a div classed "card-footer".

Thus far I've cobbled together:

```
$(".features .card").click(function() {
    if ( $(this:has("a.card-footer")) ) {
        window.location = $(this).find("a.card-footer").attr("href");
        return false;
    }
});
```

This scopes it to the cards that I need this event on, however I have not found a combination of :has/.find()/.children() that actually works.

Having to check it first as I do have card-footers in my .features cards that don't have links, so this is needed to prevent 'undefined'

Thank you.

Edit: spelling

#### Edits to fix syntax, thanks Jacob:

```
$(".features .card").click(function() {
    if ($(this).has("a.card-footer")) {
        window.location = $(this).find("a.card-footer").attr("href");
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is still picking up cards with footers that have no anchors leading to an undefined :/

#### Edit for HTML example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yg3cz214/

Comment: Is your HTML different than we're assuming, maybe? Seems to work OK for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/559999/

Comment: Ah, yes, I posted a jsfiddle above... Perhaps I was misleading about a.card-footer, its a div with class card-footer containing an anchor. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is `a.card-footer`. That means "an `a` element with the `card-footer` class". Based on your HTML structure, what you really want is "having an element with a card-footer class which has an `a` descendent"

```
$('.features .card').has('.card-footer a').click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find('.card-footer a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Just figured that out, marked this as the answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `has()` function in `jquery`:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element. https://api.jquery.com/has/

You simple then don't have to check with `if` statement. The `click event` will only execute if the `card` has an `anchor` element.

```
$('.features .card').has('.card-footer > a').click(function() {
   window.location = $(this).find('.card-footer > a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: So this with a console.log('true') renders nothing :/ I tried to post a simplified HTML example above to no avail however it's a standard bootstrap 4.1 card with a section wrapper classed to "features". Added a jsfiddle above

Comment: @ironchefbadass, I'm sorry - your description was a bit misleading. I updated the answer after the HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

#### This works

```
$('.features .card').has('.card-footer a').click(function() {
      console.log('true');
      window.location = $(this).find('.card-footer a').attr('href');
});
```

Thanks Onyx and Jacob